# Operate on column with dplyr given only partial column name

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a function that processes a number of different data frames, using `dplyr, like this:

```
some_function <- function(some_data){

    processed_data = some_data %>%
        group_by(session_id) %>% 
        arrange(some_date) %>% 
        mutate(n = row_number()) %>%
        filter(n == 1) %>%
        select(-n)    
}
```

The data frames passed to the function each share a few key column names but the others differ. In this function, I'm generally just dealing with shared column names, so it is simple to refer to them.

The exception is wanting to `arrange()` by some variable that differs systematically across data frames. e.g. it might be a column that is named `a_date` in one data frame but `b_date` in another.

So I want to operate on the column name that ends with `_date`. There are ways to operate with string representations of entire column names, but it is trickier to use some sort of matching. The `select()` function in `dplyr` has the ability to select columns using functions like `ends_with()` and so on. But how can this be achieved within other `dplyr` verbs, such as `arrange()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the *scoped* verb `arrange_at`; for your case, use `arrange_at` with `vars` + select helper functions,  `%>% arrange_at(vars(ends_with('_date')))`.

---

*Example*:

```
df <- data.frame(a_date = c(3,1,4,4), b_date = c(1,3,4,2))
```

Arrange on column `a_date`:

```
arrange_at(df, vars(starts_with('a')))
#  a_date b_date
#1      1      3
#2      3      1
#3      4      4
#4      4      2
```

Arrange on column `b_date`:

```
arrange_at(df, vars(starts_with('b')))
#  a_date b_date
#1      3      1
#2      4      2
#3      1      3
#4      4      4
```

Arrange on column `a_date` then `b_date`:

```
arrange_at(df, vars(ends_with('date')))
#  a_date b_date
#1      1      3
#2      3      1
#3      4      2
#4      4      4
```